# How to create a tall cutom navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar, xcode5

I want to create a custom navigation bar like that
[image]

Here is a default translucent navigation bar. I want to add a new view with the same background color as in the navigation bar below the navigation bar. But i don't know what is the actual colour of the navigation bar. Or maybe there is other way to create a custom navigation bar.

**Update**

I need different presentations of a navigation bar for different view controllers inside one navigation controller. Also a navigation bar should have different functionality for different controllers, that is why I don't think that subclassing a UINavigationBar is a good idea.

Comment: Have you tried subclassing `UINavigationBar` and implementing `initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass:`?

Comment: I don't know if subclassing a navigation bar is a good idea, i'll update my question.

Comment: You mean high or tall then, not wide?

Comment: Yep, sorry for my bad English

Comment: Either way, you can't do it really. You should create a custom view and controller.

Comment: I can add a view containing controls below the navigation bar. The only problem is to set the right colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19227158/722552). I removed a bottom border from a navigation bar, placed a [blur view](https://github.com/JagCesar/iOS-blur/) below the navigation bar and added a bottom border to it.