# How to change UIView top border?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicolor

I am running iOS7 and have a UINavigation controller and a UIStatusBar that are both orange, they blend perfectly, however if I load a UIView that has a UIToolbar at the top of the view over the UINavigationController it has a black line at the top as shown in the image:

[image]

I would like to know how to either get rid of this or change it to white.

I have added this code to ViewDidLoad

```
self.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
self.view.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
```

which adds a white line all around the view so the orange tool bar doesn't go right to the edge, so this is not a good solution.

Comment: I would assume this solution works for `UIToolbars` as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226965/how-to-hide-ios7-uinavigationbar-1px-bottom-line

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around, not sure if this is the best practice maybe I can get some comments on it but this is how I have fixed it.

```
myToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 45)];
[myToolBar setTranslucent:NO];
myToolBar.clipsToBounds = YES; // stop the top black line from showing.
UIView *modalViewLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.myToolBar.frame.size.width, 0.8)];
modalViewLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[myToolBar addSubview:modalViewLine];
```

The most important things being here, using **clipsToBounds** prevents the black shadow or line form appearing above the UIToolBar, then I added a UIView with a white background and that is 0.8pxl high to the top of the UIToolbar.

So if you want to stack a modal view above the current NavView it will look like this

[image]

and the deeper you go, the more lines you add per view. give a good visual que to the user so they know where they are in the application.

[image]