# How to remove border of the navigationBar in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationbar

i've been trying to remove the navigationBars border without luck. I've researched and people seem to tell to set shadowImage and BackgroundImage to nil, but this does not work in my case.

My code

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(rgba: "#4a5866")
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: ""), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage(named: "")
```

illustration:

[image]

Answer (score 361, accepted):

The trouble is with these two lines:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: ""), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage(named: "")
```

Since you don't have an image with no name, `UIImage(named: "")` returns `nil`, which means the default behavior kicks in:

> When non-nil, a custom shadow image to show instead of the default shadow image. For a custom shadow to be shown, a custom background image must also be set with -setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics: (if the default background image is used, the default shadow image will be used).

You need a truly empty image, so just initialize with `UIImage()`:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Comment: This answer really works. Because if use accepted answer (code), its remove toolbar imageViews to.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Also works when setting from UINavigationBar.appearance()

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for Swift 3.  The accepted answer worked for me in Swift 2, but not in Swift 3

Comment: This works in Swift 3. Is there a way to do it in xib?

Comment: for the swift3 you should write slightly different way:  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

Comment: i have a question, how can you bring back the shadow?

Comment: This doesn't work for me on iOS 11, no idea why... There is still a UIImageView inside _UIBarBackground inside the navigation bar.

Comment: This method conflicts with the large title in iOS 11

Comment: This answer didn't work for me. But this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50752883/1084174 works

Comment: In iOS 13, should be using `navBarAppearance`, no more need for a hack.

Comment: The current answer to this question uses `navBarAppearance` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226965/how-to-hide-uinavigationbar-1px-bottom-line

Answer (score 73):

**Swift 4 & Swift 5**

**Removing border:**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for:.default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
```

**Restoring border:**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for:.default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Do we need layoutIfNeeded() here?

Comment: Yes korgx9, we need it. Otherwise it wont change the color until next draw.

Answer (score 42):

With Swift 2 you can do it this way:

**AppDelegate file**

Inside func application(..., didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:...)

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

for Swift 3:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
```

Comment: This is the comprehensive answer!

Comment: Better to write such useful defaults at Appdelegate than to write them in the odd places. Right Answer:)

Answer (score 40):

Just write this in the extension of UINavigationBar

```
extension UINavigationBar {

    func shouldRemoveShadow(_ value: Bool) -> Void {
        if value {
            self.setValue(true, forKey: "hidesShadow")
        } else {
            self.setValue(false, forKey: "hidesShadow")
        }
    }
}
```

And in your viewController...

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shouldRemoveShadow(true)        
}
```

And to get this undone for any viewController, just pass false.

Comment: This works great BUT it hides if for ALL vcs on the nav stack. If you use it in vc1 and vc1 can push to vc2 then it will be hidden on vc2 also. To show the shadow in vc2 you will have to set it to false in viewDidLoad. The problem is when you pop back to vc1 it'll show again because it was reset in vc2. You have to use logic to go back and forth which might not be worth it. However if you don't want the shadow image to show on any vcs at all then this is the easiest way to go

Comment: Let's say we have a stack of viewControllers with 5 viewControllers(And we've hidden the shadow in the first one). Now for the 3rd viewController only, I we DON"T want to hide the shadow. So, I'll call that method with FALSE in viewWillAppear and with TRUE in viewWillDisappear of 3rd viewController. That's all it takes!

Comment: your absolutely correct, good thinking! Don't think I knocked your answer because it's very succinct and efficient, I also up voted it. I use it to remove it & the navBar for error messages. The issue I found was when removing it in vc1 but showing it vc2 but if there was an error in vc2 then removing it in viewWillDisappear might not work. But again it's a very unique situation. I do like the viewWillDisappear idea for general case use and you should add it to your answer. Regardless your code works and it's an easy way to remove the shadow! 

Comment: Works like a charm. Just wanted to make sure this isn't private settings?

Comment: @inokey it is private, from my understanding.

Comment: @nmdias will it cause any problems with uploading to AppStore in that case? Have you tried it?

Comment: @inokey I have no ideia. 'm gonna find out in a month or so when I upload an App with it.

Comment: @inokey, it won't cause any problems,  I've uploaded a build on TestFlight with this.

Comment: This is an excellent answer! I've added an answer that streamlines the code.

Comment: This is answer is not working anymore in Swift 5.8 :/

Answer (score 38):

this will remove the shadow image altogether

```
for parent in self.navigationController!.navigationBar.subviews {
 for childView in parent.subviews {
     if(childView is UIImageView) {
         childView.removeFromSuperview()
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: Also for me works this solution, while @Nate Cook's answer didn't works. :S

Comment: Holy sheist!! After all the searching, this is the ONLY thing that has worked.

Comment: it works, but also i have a menu icon in the navigation bar and it disappeared :/ i just want the border to be erased. HELP :/

Comment: This worked for me to but after pushing new ViewController it removes the line from there to. How can i prevent it from that?

Comment: This didn't work for me on iOS 11. removeFromSuperview was successfully called but the damn line is still there. It looks like it's being re-added to the navigation bar.

Answer (score 32):

**Swift 5**

When using setBackgroundImage / shadowImage to hide the hairline, there's a slight delay. This method removes the delay. Credit to [Chameleon Framework](https://github.com/viccalexander/Chameleon). This is the method they use (in ObjC)

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func hideHairline() {
        if let hairline = findHairlineImageViewUnder(navigationBar) {
            hairline.isHidden = true
        }
    }
    func restoreHairline() {
        if let hairline = findHairlineImageViewUnder(navigationBar) {
            hairline.isHidden = false
        }
    }
    func findHairlineImageViewUnder(_ view: UIView) -> UIImageView? {
        if view is UIImageView && view.bounds.size.height <= 1.0 {
            return view as? UIImageView
        }
        for subview in view.subviews {
            if let imageView = self.findHairlineImageViewUnder(subview) {
                return imageView
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, this is the only solution that worked for me on iOS 13.4...

Comment: This should be mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 29):

```
let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
navBarAppearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
```

Comment: lol, it's an inbuilt feature. Googled pages of code to find this one liner.

Comment: Only from iOS 13

Comment: You literally saved my day. self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage() is not working anymore since iOS 15. Thanks 

Comment: @Filoux It did not work for me :/
Did you put it in init?

Comment: @CCat It should work in viewDidLoad

Comment: @GIJoeCodes thanks for the reply but I tried init and onAppear and no dice. Wonder if there was a change made by Apple

Comment: Nevermind! It worked. It was conflicting with another piece of code.

Comment: This makes the whole background transparent. If you just want to get rid of the shadow use `navBarAppearance.shadowColor = UIColor.clear`.

Comment: @Wizard You're right, the most correct thing to do would be simply set the appearance shadowColor, so as not to change all other settings.

Answer (score 18):

For iOS 13+:

```swift
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.shadowColor = .clear
```

Assign this appearance to the `UINavigationBar`:

```swift
navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = appearance
```

Setting `shadowImage = UIImage()` didn't work for me.

Comment: Yep, this is the correct answer for iOS 13.0+

Answer (score 14):

Set `barStyle` to `.Black` before setting the tint:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .Black
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

Comment: is it kinda random that this actually works? or am i overthinking?

Comment: @joe well it is working here :-) does it not work for you?

Comment: that's the thing, it DOES work. i'm just wondering if there is an explanation as to why turning the barStyle to black it then turns the whole barTintColor to blue :)

Comment: maybe setting it to black and opaque, it switches off some layers/view in the navigationBar...

Comment: I tried using this, and it does remove the bottom line however if using a bar tint of white the title is not visible :/

Comment: This works. All answers did not do it for me. I am using iOS 11 swift 4.1. Thanks man.

Comment: @RileyDev I just tried it and you have to set tintColor separately for that.

Answer (score 10):

Luca Davanzo's answer is great, but it does not work in iOS 10. I altered it to work in iOS 10 and below.

```
for parent in navigationController!.view.subviews {
    for child in parent.subviews {
        for view in child.subviews { 
            if view is UIImageView && view.frame.height == 0.5 {
                view.alpha = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also extend UINavigationController and call this off of that. `removeFromSuperview()` on the line will not work on iOS 10, so I just set the alpha to 0 so this one call is compatible everywhere.

Comment: Nice catch, any way to show/hide the shadow in some viewControllers while navigating?

Comment: You should rather check for heights that have a `height >= 1.0`. 
On iPhone models that have a 3x retina screen (e.g. 8 Plus, XR...) the hairline has a height of 0.33.

Answer (score 10):

Swiftier method of Jack Chen:

```
extension UINavigationController {

    var isHiddenHairline: Bool {
        get {
            guard let hairline = findHairlineImageViewUnder(navigationBar) else { return true }
            return hairline.isHidden
        }
        set {
            if let hairline = findHairlineImageViewUnder(navigationBar) {
                hairline.isHidden = newValue
            }
        }
    }

    private func findHairlineImageViewUnder(_ view: UIView) -> UIImageView? {
        if view is UIImageView && view.bounds.size.height <= 1.0 {
            return view as? UIImageView
        }

        for subview in view.subviews {
            if let imageView = self.findHairlineImageViewUnder(subview) {
                return imageView
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Using:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.isHiddenHairline = true
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        navigationController?.isHiddenHairline = false
    }
```

Comment: This MUST be the TOP answer!

Answer (score 9):

To remove border from UINavigationBar in Swift 3+, use:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

Answer (score 8):

Only this worked for me,

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26390278/3411787)

Answer (score 7):

for swift 3

in `viewDidLoad` method

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Answer (score 6):

Updated for Swift 4 in case someone is wondering

```
navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage()
```

It's even less verbose now.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer worked for me but I noticed when I wanted the shadow image to reappear when popping back or pushing forward to another vc there was a noticeable blink in the navigation bar.

Using this method `navigationController?.navigationBar.setValue(true, forKey: "hidesShadow")`
in viewWillAppear the shadow bar is hidden in the current visible view controller.

Using these 2 methods

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.setValue(false, forKey: "hidesShadow")
```

in viewWillDisappear the blink still happens but only when the shadow image reappears and not the navigation bar itself.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // 1. hide the shadow image in the current view controller you want it hidden in
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setValue(true, forKey: "hidesShadow")
    navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)

    // 2. show the shadow image when pushing or popping in the next view controller. Only the shadow image will blink
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setValue(false, forKey: "hidesShadow")
    navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove only the bottom line and keep the solid color of navigationBar, add these lines of code in viewDidLoad:
Swift 3, 4:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

Peace!

Answer (score 2):

This is the way if you want to do it without changing the background color:

```
// Remove the border ImageView from the NavigationBar background
func hideBottomBorder() {
    for view in navigationBar.subviews.filter({ NSStringFromClass($0.dynamicType) == "_UINavigationBarBackground" }) as [UIView] {
        if let imageView = view.subviews.filter({ $0 is UIImageView }).first as? UIImageView {
            imageView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE:
This might crash on a production app. Apparently the NavigationBar doesn't like its view disappearing

Answer (score 2):

Within **AppDelegate**, this has globally changed the format of the NavBar and removes the bottom line/border:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarPosition: UIBarPosition.Any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = false
    //UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : (UIFont(name: "FONT NAME", size: 18))!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()] }
```

Haven't managed to implement anything different on a specific VC, but this will help 90% of people

Comment: UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

in your custom navigationController add these lines:

```
self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for:.default)
self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
```

## Important Note

the last line is important if you use the first line viewDidLoad() method because navigationController should redraw nav bar but easily you can use this without layoutIfNeeded() in the viewWillAppear() method before it draws the nav bar

Answer (score 1):

for the swift3 you should write slightly different way:

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(),
    for: UIBarMetrics.default)
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a streamlined version of [Gaurav Chandarana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6268907/gaurav-chandarana)'s answer.

```
extension UINavigationBar {

    func hideShadow(_ value: Bool = true) {
        setValue(value, forKey: "hidesShadow")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

App delegate

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this code in AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method to reach it in whole app:

```
 let barAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    
 if #available(iOS 13, *) {
     let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
     appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
     barAppearance.standardAppearance = appearance
     barAppearance.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
 } else {
     barAppearance.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarPosition.any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.defaultPrompt)
     barAppearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The border line is an UIImageView and removing a subview which is an imageView will remove barButtonItems with UIImageView. Below code will help you remove it. Hope this helps someone who faced an issue like me.

```
for parent in self.navigationController!.navigationBar.subviews {
        for childView in parent.subviews {
            if childView.frame.height == 0.5 {
                childView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
```

The border UIImageView is only 0.5 in height so this code removes only that.

Comment: This caused crashes for me. I think parent and childViews need to be unwrapped in case they're nil before checking each one. I am using a custom UINavigationController though, so this might not be the case for other users with a standard bar.

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer in swift 3 base of Nate Cook answer

```
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Answer (score 0):

**iOS 11 and Swift 4** You should try following if you want to remove the border but don't to make the navigitonbar translucent 

`self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()`

Answer (score 0):

I am using Xcode 14.2. If you want to do this using Xcode UI, then select the Navigation controller, then Navigation Bar, then Attributes Inspector and Under Scroll Edge Appearance, set the Shadow Color to clear color.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found changing the navigation bar shadow color to **Clear** from the **activity inspector** to solve this issue

[**changing the navigation bar shadow color****strong text**][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3Kdo.png***strong text***