# iOS UISearchBar remove faint lines in Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uisearchbar

I'm trying to remove these thin dark lines from the Xcode Search Bar Controller (see Image 1 below).

[image: Image 1]

I created a class but there is no property available for border-width (which looks like that was the solution in Objective-C)

Is this even a problem with the Search Bar, if I scroll up it looks like the line is part of my Navigation Controller, it looks like they might both create a thin line (see Image 2 below)

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Try using the view debugger to see if you can see what it's attached to (or Reveal App if that's not good enough).  It's the "Debug View Hierarchy" button in the debugger once you are on the screen you want to examine.

Comment: It's called the 'hairline', just search for that.

Comment: I think this is a better answer than the one in the 'duplicate': https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390072/remove-border-in-navigationbar-in-swift/32405760#32405760