# What are the rgb equivalent colors to the navigation bar's .isTranslucent color?

Tags: ios, swift, view, uinavigationbar, uicolor

[image]

The navigation bar has a `.isTranslucent` property that gives it that gray background color

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

I want my entire view controller to match that same exact color and `.lightGray` isn't it. I tried playing with the view controller's view's `.alpha` and `.isOpaque` properties but I cannot get it to match.

Does anyone know the rgb colors or another way I can get my view controller's view's background color to match that same translucent gray color?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // I tried playing with different combinations of all of these in different ways

    view.backgroundColor = .lightGray

    view.alpha = .5

    view.isOpaque = false
}
```

Comment: It's translucent, that means it depends on the background behind the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would set the view  and navigation bar to the same colour:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red   : 249.0/255.0,
                               green : 249.0/255.0,
                               blue  : 249.0/255.0,
                               alpha : 1.0)
```

[image: cap]

The seam would still be there. If you'd like to remove it :

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Comment: I was using that to remove the shadow image but making it reappear in another vc when pushing or popping was a headache because the navigation bar blinked when reappearing. I used this instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/55080068/4833705

Comment: Might be easier to do: `view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 249.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)`

Comment: @rmaddy: Good alternative