# SwiftUI Remove NavigationBar Bottom Border

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When using SwiftUI how do you remove the bottom 1px border of a navigation bar?

[image: iOS SwiftUI NavigationBar Example]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In the initializer of your View you can set the appearance of your navigation bar. There you have to set the `.shadowColor` property to `.clear`.

```
init() {
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.shadowColor = .clear
    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
}
```

Comment: No longer working on Xcode 13.2 and iOS 15

Comment: @CCat Just tested this on Xcode 14.1 and it still works for me. Did you add the code in the initializer of your View?

Comment: Can confirm that this still works. However, the above code needs to be placed in the init of the root view

Comment: this code doesn't work at all, wherever I put the code.

Answer (score 10):

I have also met this problem. Here is the almost similar  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390072/how-to-remove-border-of-the-navigationbar-in-swift)

But most of the answer had side effect. And for me, the best solution was this

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .clear
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear 
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

and also want its important to set UIImage() not 'nil' to shadowImage  and bacgroundImage.  And I made navigation displayMode inline

```
.navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Comment: This is just repeating what other answers are saying. Like first line of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66002653/2227743) or third line of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61092866/2227743).

Answer (score 0):

if you are calling `UINavigationBarAppearance().configureWithDefaultBackground()` do not forget to set `appearance.shadowColor = .clear` only after it:

```
extension UINavigationBar {
    static func changeAppearance(clear: Bool) {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()

        // Before
        // appearance.shadowColor = .clear

        if clear {
            appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        } else {
            appearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
        }

        // After
        appearance.shadowColor = .clear

        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    init() {
        UINavigationBar.changeAppearance(clear: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

SwiftUI, 1 line.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance.shadowColor = .clear
```

I implemented that inside .onAppear {}

Answer (score -1):

In Xcode 12.4, this is the combination that worked for me:

```
init() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.red
}
```