# overlay view not tight on the UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to add an overlay view (`addSubview`) and have it "extend" the status bar + navigationBar

So I made a xib that has a red view, with a constraint of Top alignment of 64.

Still I have black line between the status bar and the red view (see image)

If I change the constraint to less - the red view in under the status bar, but still there is a black line.

The code that adds the view:

```
    overlaySearchView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"searchView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    overlaySearchView.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
//    overlaySearchView.frame = self.view.bounds; //tried both


    [[self view] addSubview:overlaySearchView];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See answer here: [How to hide iOS7 UINavigationBar 1px bottom line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226965/how-to-hide-ios7-uinavigationbar-1px-bottom-line)

What you are seeing is the shadow of the navigation bar, rather than a gap between the two views.

Answer (score 0):

please select the view controller and in attribute inspector tab check/uncheck

1. under top bars and
2. under bottom bar options

Hope it helps!

Comment: yes i know, but this view will be in a viewcontroller :-) select the viewcontroller and give it a try.

Comment: Under Top Bars and Under Opaque Bars in the original ViewController is checked...

Comment: exactly the same (after unchecking it and changing the constraint to 0) - nice try...

Comment: add top contraint for the overlay view then, hope it will do the trcik.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying to modify your `self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height`?

If that works you can then add a custom `navigationItem.titleView` with all your other views in it.