# Remove bar below navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

[image]

On **presenting navigation controller** over **tabbar controller**, there is a **bar below the navigation bar**. Please suggest any solutions for this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226965/how-to-hide-ios7-uinavigationbar-1px-bottom-line ?

Comment: @Wain..Please see my updated screen shot...I need to remove the grey color bar which is below the navigation bar. I want to display only the navigation bar

Comment: Can you debug UI and see wtf is that bar and where it comes from? Because if it's not your shadow thing then you probably put it yourself there.

Comment: Are you using sections? It looks like a section title without text.

Comment: @bushiko No I don't have table view at all

Comment: If you don't understand the question please don't give down vote..one who knows the answer may skip the question because of your down vote.

Comment: If you're using the new Xcode, there is a 3D layer browser for your running app so you can click and select, pan around, zoom in and see the name of the view.

Comment: Can you explain in detail? how can I select, pan around, zoom in?