# How to modify the color of hairline of uinavigationbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I've known the way to get the hairline view, which is a UIImageView, from this question:[How to hide iOS7 UINavigationBar 1px bottom line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226965/how-to-hide-ios7-uinavigationbar-1px-bottom-line/19227158#19227158)

but, to modify this view's background color is so bad experience,
code like this:

```
    [[self findHairlineImageViewUnder:self.navigationController.navigationBar] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"ff0000"]];
```

the findHairlineImageViewUnder method is from the answer link above

this works, but not always, even put in `viewdidload`,`viewwillapear`,`viewDidLayoutSubviews`, it will go back to original color at some scene, like after push and pop.

so, I'd like to ask if there is some perfect way to change the color of hairline of uinavigationbar, thanks.

Comment: This seems to work fine for me: https://github.com/samwize/UINavigationBar-Addition

Answer (score 1):

now I found addd a subview to the hairline's superview did the trick and works fine

```
    UIView* sv= [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[self findHairlineImageViewUnder:self.navigationController.navigationBar].frame];
sv.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"ff0000"];
[[self findHairlineImageViewUnder:self.navigationController.navigationBar].superview addSubview:sv];
```