# How can I remove border bottom of UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, navigationbar

I want to remove the bottom border from `UINavigationBar`, but I don't know how to remove it.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide iOS7 UINavigationBar 1px bottom line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226965/how-to-hide-ios7-uinavigationbar-1px-bottom-line)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, that is the *shadow* of the navigation bar.

To get rid of it, just set it to an empty image:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

**Note:** You must set it to an empty `UIImage()`; `nil` won't work for some reason.

Comment: The documentation says it would just work when setting the backgroundImage with, but it worked for me without the backgroundImage as the code in this answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a custom shadow image to show instead of the default one. Note: a custom background image must also be set.

```
navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = .blue //set your color
navController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

navController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
navController.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;
```

OR

you can give border color same as navigation bar background color

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:<#(CGFloat)#> green:<#(CGFloat)#> blue:<#(CGFloat)#> alpha:<#(CGFloat)#>];
```

Comment: all no use in iOS 10.2

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 11 you can use the (deprecated) Black Translucent Navigation bar style with a custom bar tint.