# How to hide 1px UINavigationBar hairline from the middle of the UINavigation Bar

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have added UINavigation bar with a background image.

But unfortunately an unwanted 1px hairline is displaying at the middle of the UINavigation Bar.

I want to hide that line, but it's not working. I have added following code.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:nil];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarImg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add the navBarImg.png also?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19227158/4910767

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do not need to set the navigationbar become transparent, you can use the following code

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[self imageFromColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]] forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

and adding the following method to generate an uiimage.

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromColor:(UIColor *)color {
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
```

}