# How can I add UIButton right underneath navigation bar seamlessly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am adding a button in the centre and right underneath my navigation bar. Problem here is that the navigation bar will look like it's cutting off due to its shadow & tint.

How can I incorporate the UIButton so that it looks like it's a part of the navigation bar like this:

```
____navbar _______   
    l_____|
```

If I just add a UIButton right underneath the nav bar, it will just look like this:

```
__________________
     l______|
```

The button will be used to drag or drop down another uiviewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to remove the 1px line that acts as the border or shadow for the `UINavigationBar`. You can find the way of doing that in the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19227158/569507