# How to remove navigation bar border/shadow?

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a navigation bar and it has a horizontal line that I'd like to remove.

[image: Screenshot]

I have removed the nav bar color from the screenshot to make the line more apparent.

I have tried setting the shadow image property of the navigation bar to a blank png (1x1 pixel pngs for 1x, 2x and 3x), but there's no effect.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Those two lines of code always do the trick for me :

```
 navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Comment: For swift3:
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "img_name"),for:.default)

Comment: I have barTint and tintColor set for the navigationBar. After doing what you suggested, the barTint is not being respected and it is turning back to white. Any suggestions there?

Comment: `navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)` this line is causing my navigationBar to not respect barTint

Comment: @TheRohanSanap if you're talking about `barTintColor`, then just set it after `setBackgroundImage()`

Comment: Can't edit, but you also have to set `.isTranslucent = false`. In my case I set it before setting `barTintColor`

Comment: @Xernox No, that doesn't help. The method described in the above answer not only removes the bottom shadow but also makes the navigation bar clear. To remove the bottom shadow with retaining the barTintColor, follow this answer - > http://stackoverflow.com/a/19227158/4618125

Comment: @TheRohanSanap Are you referring to the original answer or to my suggestion? Because my suggestion does work and does not make navigation bar clear color.

Comment: @Xernox your suggestion doesn't work with me.

Comment: @Vishnuvardhan 's answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226965/how-to-hide-uinavigationbar-1px-bottom-line/19227158#19227158 does not remove barTintColor.

Comment: This always worked for me except iOS 15 appears to require an image with content - I updated to use an image that's just a solid color.

Answer (score 24):

If you want to do it globally you can do:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
```

Comment: Works except when it segues into another view controller, my nav bar has no color.

Comment: Where would you set this--- I am guessing in AppDel? Sample code?

Comment: Update for Swift 4:

UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)

Comment: @EdmundElmer ios 13 in not remove shadow

Comment: This always worked for me except iOS 15 appears to require an image with content - I updated to use an image that's just a solid color.