# Having title & items stay in place while extending navigationBar height

Tags: swift, navigationbar

I'm trying to extend the height of my navigation bar but whenever I change the height, the title and items moves along with it.

Using `setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment` I can make the title stay in place but that only works for the title. How can I make the rightBarButtonItem stay in place like the title?

I've also tried to change the frame of the customView of the `UIBarButtonitem` but that didn't work either.

Perhaps I could subclass the navigation bar and add some auto layout to the title label, left and right bar button items?

Comment: Did you consider adding custom subview below navigation bar?

Comment: Yes, that's what I originally had. But because because of some strange reason, there's a small area beneath the navigation bar making the touches not being registered by the custom view.

Comment: Yes, I remember your other question. But in this question you added custom view to navigation bar itself. I meant add it to your view controller's view.

Comment: That would work, but then it doesn't look like my navigation bar is extended. The border of the navigation bar then  would be visible.

Comment: You can remove border. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226965/how-to-hide-ios7-uinavigationbar-1px-bottom-line

Comment: You're right. Gotta try if I can fix this by doing what you've suggested. Thanks!

Comment: The problem about not being able to tap the custom subview still remains even adding it to the view of the view controller though.