# How to remove the separator line between Master Detail Page and Content Page in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I remove the gray separator line between the status bar u from the Content page
This is a Master Detail Page with a Content Page as the Detail.

See screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226965/how-to-hide-ios7-uinavigationbar-1px-bottom-line) SO question, you can create a custom renderer similar to this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(CustomNavigationPage))]
namespace CustomNavigationPage.iOS
{
    public class CustomNavigationPage : NavigationRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(new UIKit.UIImage(), UIKit.UIBarMetrics.Default);
            NavigationBar.ShadowImage = new UIKit.UIImage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Paul, where would I create this? In the ios project Sorry, I am new to Xamarin world.

Comment: In the iOS project. See the guides for more information on custom renderers and getting started with them: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/