# Make navigationBar border invisible

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, border

As the tile says I simply need to find a way to make invisible the lower border of the navigationBar like the photo below:

[image]

could anyone help me?!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226965/how-to-hide-ios7-uinavigationbar-1px-bottom-line

Comment: Ok, it seems what i need, but i'm not able to traduce to swift, could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code from that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226965/how-to-hide-ios7-uinavigationbar-1px-bottom-line), just add this in your AppDelegate.swift
to make it global.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(
    UIImage(),
    forBarPosition: .Any,
    barMetrics: .Default)

UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Comment: Ok, i also tried this in the controller self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
but your solution is much better