# How to add shadow to Navigation Bar instead of default border

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want to replace a default border in `UINavigationBar` with shadow. Is there any way to achieve this? I have tried using the same approach as with adding shadow to UIView but it increases a height of my NavigationBar.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

try this

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0)
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
```

**Swift 3**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
 }
```

**output as**

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Abnu.Karthik! It has almost solved my problem but there is still a small issue. The border of color of black is still there.. Can I hide it somehow?

Comment: see rthis once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226965/how-to-hide-ios7-uinavigationbar-1px-bottom-line