# UINavigation with UITextField as subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to make UI like following,

[image]

I tried to increase the height of UINavigationController like

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 110)];
```

but navigation title and BarButtonItem appears down.
i can not add hide navigation as i am using third party side menu which uses Left BarButtonItem.

i can very well keep navigation as it is and below i have added uiview as subview with same background colour as that of navigation but there is fine line appears in between...:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't increase height of UINavigationBar. Add an UIView with those elements just below the UINavigationBar.

Then there will be extra line below UINavigationBar. You can remove that line. Refer [How to hide iOS7 UINavigationBar 1px bottom line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226965/how-to-hide-ios7-uinavigationbar-1px-bottom-line)

or else use this code(I have just copied it from that link in swift, convert it to Objective-C)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var shadowImageView: UIImageView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if shadowImageView == nil {
            shadowImageView = findShadowImage(under: navigationController!.navigationBar)
        }
        shadowImageView?.isHidden = true
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        shadowImageView?.isHidden = false
    }

    private func findShadowImage(under view: UIView) -> UIImageView? {
        if view is UIImageView && view.bounds.size.height <= 1 {
            return (view as! UIImageView)
        }

        for subview in view.subviews {
            if let imageView = findShadowImage(under: subview) {
                return imageView
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

This is the result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cant change height of `UINavigationBar`. Your actual ViewController's view will start from 64 pixel from `TopLayoutGuide` (Vertical Space)
Status Bar Height is 20 Pixel
Navigation Bar Height is 44 Pixel

So to design such UI, simply do these steps

1. Hide `NavigationBar` on that view controller like

   self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
   self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
2. Then add View from storyboard with `vertical space` as 0 from `TopLayoutGuide`. And design it as per your requirement. So you can
   simply give this look and handle it using `IBOutlets` and `IBActions`
   for each item

Also you can add `UILable` to show title of screen.

Comment: i can not add hide navigation as i am using third party side menu which uses Left BarButtonItem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't increase the size of the UINavigationBar. That is of standard size 44 (Nav Height) + 20  (size of the status bar). Here you've two options to achieve.

First, by adding menu, dashboard title label & notification icon to the UINavigationBar. Add Jobs, Conditions, and Interview as a separate view below to navigation bar.

Second by customizing the entire view, as mentioned by @Pushkraj i.e, by hiding the current Navigation Bar and adding your own view which contains all the UI elements.