# hide separator line of navigation bar and keep the status bar the same color as the nav bar

Tags: ios, swift

I call

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

in viewDidLoad.

Looks like this:
[image]

The separator line below the navigation bar disappears fine.  The problem is, the status bar turns white. I want it to stay the same color as the navigation bar.

if just

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

in viewDidLoad, looks like this:

[image]

below the nav bar I have a view the exact same colour as the nav bar. I want this blended into one so it looks like the view below the nav bar is part of the nav bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working for me. Can u check this answer.

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blue
 self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
 // Add your colour
```

Comment: `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false` done the trick. Thanks

Comment: You can find the solution in the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226965/how-to-hide-uinavigationbar-1px-bottom-line

Answer (score 0):

Your statusbar become white after you call `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)`, because your `viewController.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` is `NO`, so when you set a opaque background image for the navigationBar, the navigationBar's background will not start from `0` but from `20`, and nothing behind the statusbar, and statusbar showing as white.

So you must call `viewController.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES` to avoid the white statusbar.

Custom shadowImage only work if you set a custom background image for the `UINavigationBar`.