# How do I remove only the border color of NavigationBar in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I wish to retain the navigationBar background color and image, but don't know how to remove (only) the border color.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide iOS7 UINavigationBar 1px bottom line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226965/how-to-hide-ios7-uinavigationbar-1px-bottom-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 3, I figured it out by simply doing this:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage();
```