# UISearchController in UITabBarController - strange white line appearing when NavBar collapses

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I can't figure out why there is this white line appearing when I click in the search text field. The only way to prevent it from happening is to make the `navigationBar.isTranslucent = false`, but this is not an ideal solution. Does anyone know why this might be happening and how to fix it?

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController {

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search..."
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    definesPresentationContext = true

    ...
}
```

#### Update

I've determined that the `UITabBarController` is to blame for this annoyance, but I don't know why or how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to identify the view within the hierarchy browser? Is it potentially the shadow image (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226965/how-to-hide-uinavigationbar-1px-bottom-line)?

Comment: @Jamie tried a bunch of these solutions but nothing worked. I've determined that it is related to this view being embedded in a `UITabBarController`.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue.