# Xamarin.Forms on IOS: Remove space between SearchBar and NavigationBar

Tags: ios, xamarin, uisearchbar, searchbar

in my page, i added a SearchBar above a ListView. It works good but i see a small line between the NavigationBar and the SearchBar. Anyone knows how to remove it?
Thanks

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <SearchBar 
        CancelButtonColor="White"
        BackgroundColor="{x:Static local:Consts.PrimaryColor}"
        IsVisible="{Binding IsSearchVisible, Mode=OneWay}"
    />
    <ListView
```

[image: Space between navigation bar and search bar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove bottom shadow line you can use custom renderer. That going to do exactly what you need.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(NoLineNavigationRenderer))] 
namespace MyMobileProject.iOS {
    public class NoLineNavigationRenderer : NavigationRenderer {

        public override void ViewDidLoad(){
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            // remove lower border and shadow of the navigation bar
            NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
            NavigationBar.ShadowImage = new UIImage ();
        }
    }
}
```

For more information you can visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226965/how-to-hide-uinavigationbar-1px-bottom-line)

Comment: thanks. i was searching wrong. i thought it had something to do with the SearchBar.