# Unable to remove the shadow Image from navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am writing this in `viewDidLoad()` for the same

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

However this doesn't work on iOS versions < 11
What should I do in an order to remove shadow image irrespective of iOS version.

Getting:
 [image: Getting now]
Expected:
 [image: Expectation]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide UINavigationBar 1px bottom line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226965/how-to-hide-uinavigationbar-1px-bottom-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `viewDiDLoad()` add this:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setValue(true, forKey: "hidesShadow")
```

For me worked

Answer (score 7):

Try the following code:

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Use of unresolved identifier 'navigationBar'

Comment: Why are you changing the background image too. I have a background color on it!