# How to remove 1px bottom border from UINavigationBar *with* a UISearchController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a navigation bar which includes a `UISearchController`, and I cannot find a way to get rid of the 1px bottom border below the navigation bar:

[image]

I am already using the tricks for removing the navigation bar bottom border as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19227158/368085) and many others:

```swift
navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(aTransparentImage, for: .default)
navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
```

If I don't set the `searchController` on the `navigationItem` of my view controller it's fine, there is no bottom border, but as soon as I set the `searchController` it appears.

Even the dirty hacks that look for a 1px `UIImageView` in the nav bar view hierarchy don't work, as it seems this view is in a separate tree of the hierarchy. It's the `UIImageView` highlighted in blue below:

[image]

I'm out of ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, a colleague of mine provided a solution. In `viewWillAppear` in the view controller which is showing the search bar do:

```swift
if let imageView = navigationItem.searchController?
    .searchBar.superview?
    .subviews.first?
    .subviews.last as? UIImageView,
    imageView.frame.height * UIScreen.main.scale == 1.0 {
    imageView.isHidden = true
}
```

This is obviously highly dependent on the exact view hierarchy that UIKit is using for the search bar, and could stop working with any future release of iOS (it works on iOS 12). You could make it more resilient by searching the superview subviews for a 1px height `UIImageView`, but still, it's quite a hack.

But so far, it's the only solution I have found that works.

Comment: faced same issue , is there any other better idea you found out..?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

or

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

in ViewDidLoad Method. It worked for me