# How to add shadow to navigation bar and hide border in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently adding a shadow to my navigation bar using the following code:

```swift
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 4.0)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

This produces the following result:
[image]
The shadow is being shown correctly, however I do not want the 1px black border of the navigation bar to be shown, I only want the navigation bar to have a shadow. I know that setting the shadow property of the navigation bar to an empty image removes the border, but that also hides the shadow. Is there any way to achieve a shadow without a border?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33477140/4539192).

Comment: This hides the shadow as well as the border. I'm looking for a way to show a shadow without a border.

Comment: Mhm I thought since you are changing the image and not shadow property, that would work! My bad

Comment: What if you hide the shadow this way: `navigationController?.navigationBar.setValue(true, forKey: "hidesShadow")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this extension:

```
extension UIView {
fileprivate var hairlineImageView: UIImageView? {
    return hairlineImageView(in: self)
}

fileprivate func hairlineImageView(in view: UIView) -> UIImageView? {
    if let imageView = view as? UIImageView, imageView.bounds.height <= 1.0 {
        return imageView
    }

    for subview in view.subviews {
        if let imageView = self.hairlineImageView(in: subview) { return imageView }
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

Add this line after nav bar shadow in viewWillAppear:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.hairlineImageView?.isHidden = true
```

IF YOU WANT TO SEE THAT THE LINE IS GONE comment nav bar shadow and set table view separator color to clear...

```
//navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
//navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 4.0)
//navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
//navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
//navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
    
navigationController?.navigationBar.hairlineImageView?.isHidden = true
tableView.separatorColor = .clear
```

[image]

Comment: For the second part, I am getting the error "Value of type 'UINavigationBar' has no member 'hairlineImageView'".

Comment: Hi, I just checked again and there is still the same error. There is no hairlineImageView property under the navigationBar. Also, I am trying to show a shadow but only a shadow, right now with the code I have the shadow Is showing but with the 1px line underneath.

Comment: @TOPCOD3R you're right, i forgot to put in the extension... I update my answer, sorry...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this just hides the 1px line. Is there any way to add a shadow now? I would like a shadow but without the line if it is possible.

Comment: @TOPCOD3R Uncomment your shadow... the second part is only for show that the line is gone...

Comment: @TOPCOD3R Have a nice WE :)