# Header has border with XF 5.0.0.2196 on iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms

When I upgrade my iOS application to the Xamarin Forms 5.0.0.2125 to 5.0.0.2196 I have a border under the header of my application.

Old:
[image]

New:
[image]

It is on pages with and without custom title. So I presume that this is a global setting. Is there a way to override that again?

Edit:

I tried the followings, unfortunately without success:

Adding the following lines in the FinishedLaunching in the AppDelegate:

```
        UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
        UINavigationBar.Appearance.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
```

Or add this, which should work from iOS 13 upwards:

```
       UINavigationBar.Appearance.StandardAppearance = null;
```

Or since I read that there is a bug in iOS 15 this version:

```
            var appearance = new UINavigationBarAppearance()
            {
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear, ShadowColor = null,
            };

            UINavigationBar.Appearance.StandardAppearance = appearance;
            UINavigationBar.Appearance.ScrollEdgeAppearance = appearance;
            UINavigationBar.Appearance.CompactAppearance = appearance;
```

Unfortunately all those where without success.

Edit: GitHub Link https://github.com/MoneyFox/MoneyFox

Comment: I test both on  5.0.0.2125 and 5.0.0.2196 ,it's the same result , there is border(line) under the toolbar , which version of simulator did you test on , and could you try this on a real device to see if problem persists.

Comment: Actually I noticed it first on my real device (Iphone 12 with iOS 15). But I also have it on a Simulator of the latest xCode with MacOs Monterey.

Comment: Or the other question if you say that there is usually a borderline on the toolbar: is there a way I can remove that border?

Answer (score 0):

Try to override `BackgroundImage` and `shadowImage` on `UINavigationBar`  in AppDelegate .

Try the following code , it works on my side .

```
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate  
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());

            //add thie line
            UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
            UINavigationBar.Appearance.ShadowImage = new UIImage();

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
    }
```

Refer to [How to hide UINavigationBar 1px bottom line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226965/how-to-hide-uinavigationbar-1px-bottom-line).

Comment: sorry my late response! I tried your code as well as other options under your link. But so far it didn't work unfortunately. I updated my original post with more information what I tried. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: Since the code is working on my side,  I need more information to reproduce your problem . Are you developing `Shell` or `None-Shell` project ? Are you using  a `FlyoutPage`? If so could you provide the code in shared project ?

Comment: I'm using Shell. The project is actually open source. I linked the github repo.

Comment: This is a potential issue in Shell project , I tried to create custom renderer and tried all the ways online but no luck , the navigation bar must be redrawn somewhere  it is a black box  , consider raise this issue on :https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues.

Comment: The issue is opened here: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14938